# MongoDB group by (id1, id2) or (id2,id1)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, aggregation

I am building a basic messaging system with mongodb and I store messages like this:

Message Schema:

```
{
    senderId: ObjectId,
    receiverId: ObjectId
    createdAt: Date
}
```

I want to display all message threads between a user and other users.
So I want to filter all messages that contain the requesting user.

But after that step I dont know how to group the messages by senderId or receiverId.

```
$group: {
    _id: {
      senderId: '$senderId',
      receiverId: '$receiverId'
    },
    messages: {
      $push: {
        _id: '$_id',
        body: '$body',
        attachment: '$attachment',
        senderId: '$senderId',
        receiverId: '$receiverId'
      }
    }
}
```

This grouping treats messages sent by the requesting user and messages received by the sending user as 2 different groups.

Ideally, i can group all messages between 2 users and then select the latest messaged based on the createdAt time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: whats the problem here? Code looks fine to me. You are grouping by senderId and receiverId and getting messages for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could swap the ids so that the smaller one is always `a` and the bigger one always `b`:

```
 _id: { $cond: {
  if: { $gte: ["$senderId", "$receiverId"] },
  then: {
    a: '$senderId',
    b: '$receiverId'
  },
  else: {
   a: '$receiverId',
   b: '$senderId'
  }
} },
```